# Unable to access an element of a boolean state array in swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a struct as below

```
struct ValidStruct : Identifiable{
    var id: UUID
    var isValid = true
}
```

I then have a view that has a *State* property that is an array of ValidStruct

```
struct ValidityDetailView: View {
    @State var isValidCollection: [ValidStruct] = []
```

some where in this view I have code similar to below

```
var body: some View {
  ScrollView{
            LazyVStack{
                let elt = detail["validObjects"] as! OrderedDictionary<String, Any>?

                ForEach(0..<elt!.count){ index in

                            HStack{
                                    Text("\(isValidCollection[index].isValid) ? "Not valid" : "Valid")")
                                        .font(.title2)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            isValidCollection[index].isValid.toggle()
                                        }
...
}
}
}
}.onAppear{
  //initialize and populate isValidCollection array here
        let elt = detail["validObjects"] as! OrderedDictionary<String, Any>?
        isValidCollection = Array(repeating: ValidStruct(id: UUID(), isValid: false), count: elt!.count)
        print(">>> isValidCollection count \($isValidCollection.count)")
}
}
```

The code above crashes the preview. What am I doing wrong please?

Expected to see a preview filled with vertical rows of Text ui elements

Answer (score 0):

First of all force downcasting an optional to an optional

```
let elt = detail["validObjects"] as! OrderedDictionary<String, Any>?
```

is pointless.

- If you want a conditional downcast replace the exclamation mark with a question mark and remove the question mark at the end.
- If you want to force downcast the optional remove the question mark.

---

The error occurs because `isValidCollection` is empty when the view is rendered the first time but `elt!.count` in `ForEach` has a value and you get an out-of-bounds crash. Instead use `isValidCollection.count` and remove the `let elt = …` line

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        LazyVStack{
            ForEach(0..<isValidCollection.count){ index in
                HStack {
                    Text(isValidCollection[index].isValid ? "Not valid" : "Valid")
                       .font(.title2)
                       .onTapGesture {
                            isValidCollection[index].isValid.toggle()
                       }
...
}
```

Other notes:

- `isExpanded` is more likely `isValid`.
- Don't use the ternary operator inside a String Interpolation.
- It's more efficient to declare `id` as constant and `isValid` as `false` as this seems to be the default value

  ```
    struct ValidStruct : Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        var isValid = false
    }
  ```

Then you can initialize the array

```
isValidCollection = Array(repeating: ValidStruct(), count: elt!.count)
```

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue from your remarks and code, much appreciated for the fast response chief.

Comment: @JonDoe if this solves your problem then mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I'm unable to as I do not have 15 reputation